# Error while deploying to heroku: rake assets:precompile PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deployment

While trying to git push the application to heroku, i get this specific error:

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile 
remote:        PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection     refused
remote:        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
remote:        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried to follow the steps of the article : `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting`

And my assets were compiling locally without the need of a connection to a data base.

I have added also the `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

But the error still occurs when trying to deploy in heroku...

Any idea about what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks!

P.S: I am using spree 3.0.0 with rails 4.2.0

Comment: Maybe you forgot commit to git after adding config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

Comment: What is your gemfile loading in production?

Answer (score 8):

Create new db in heroku for your app: 
`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql`

Then try git push to heroku